# Copying selected text with QTextCursor

Tags: python, copy, selection, pyside, qtextcursor

These are the widgets that I have,

```
self.recipient = QTextEdit(self)
self.document = QTextDocument(self)
self.recipient.setDocument(self.document)
self.cursor = QTextCursor(self.document)
```

and what I want to do is use the `QTextCursor` to copy the selected text in my `QTextEdit`. I have tried the function `selectedText()`, but it gives me an empty string. Here is how I try to print it:

```
print('%s' % (self.cursor.selectedText()))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to retrieve the current cursor from the text-edit:

```
    cursor = self.recipient.textCursor()
    print('%s' % (cursor.selectedText()))
```

But note that this cursor is only a copy. If you make changes to it, those changes won't immediately update the text-edit. To do that, you need to reset the cursor, like this:

```
    # make some changes to the cursor
    cursor.select(QtGui.QTextCursor.LineUnderCursor)
    # update the text-edit
    self.recipient.setTextCursor(cursor)
```